# Why is $body.children() including elements that are not within the <body></body> tags?

Tags: html, children

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
    <p>one</p>
    <p>two</p>
    <p>three</p>
</body>
<script>
var $body = $('body');
var children = $body.children();
alert(children.length) //-> 4
</html>
```

I expect `alert(children.length)` to alert `3` instead of `4` because there are only three elements inside the `<body>` tags. When I iterate through children, it reveals that 3 elements are `<p>` elements (as expected), while the fourth is the `<script>` element. Why is the `<script>` element included within the children of body, when it is not within `<body>` tags in the HTML?

Comment: Because your HTML in invalid and a typical browser will attempt to correct it by placing the script *within* the body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only `<head>` and `<body>` can go in `<html>`. Your `<script>` tag is placed incorrectly, so the browser error-corrects it back into `<body>`.